# Restoring openssl to Ubuntu out of the box version

Tags: openssl

Is there a way I can restore openssl and its configuration to the version that came with Ubuntu, I messed up my own version and now whatever i do get errors like:

```
<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)>
```

Which has been driving me crazy because nothing from the internet either does not seem to work or just say i validate the specific site's certificate. This used to work before and I frankly didn't know what I was getting myself into when I was messing the openssl installation.

My last attempt to reinstall is from here -> https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-openssl-from-source-on-linux/ and the version i used is `1.1.1g`.

Any help on this please and while doing so, just concider am not a guru in linux, because my next option is just to reinstall ubuntu altogether which i don't want to and am positive there is a way out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "way out" is to systemically revert back any changes you've made. If you don't remember what you did, the faster path is probably a reinstall. I suggest documenting your steps and creating backups of files that you change. Generally before I edit any config, I will run `sudo cp that.config that.config.bak`, that way all you have to do to restore is look for the `.bak` files, remove the one you fiddled with and and remove the `.bak` extension from your backup so that it's now the primary

Comment: well i don't remember doing that, i just updated and honestly i didn't think it would result to this

Comment: If you know what files you changed, you could boot from a live session and compare the files on that with the ones installed on your system. If you're fairly new to linux it's pretty common to find and follow a guide, and very easy to just do it blindly, but if you take your time to research and understand each step before you do it, you will learn a lot about the thing you're fixing and the knowledge is cumulative.  Hang in there ;)

Comment: thanks, though on the research part, I have already spent almost quarter of a day, that's why I resorted to online help, I feel like I have already spent alot of time on this

Comment: I've been there! You generally reach a point where you realize it's faster easier and less stressful to just reinstall and call it experience gained

Comment: yea, exactly, and also, lesson learned ;)